# Access to fields of on reverse relation in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys

I have these models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()

class Report(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(
        Task, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=Status.CHOICES, default=Status.INCOMPLETE)
```

Now I want to get all `Task`s and their related status.

How do I do this?

Comment: it's going to be hard when you have explicitly disabled the reverse relation you need by specifying `related_name='+'`. otherwise see the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, `'+'` is not a valid `related_name`. It is also not very explicit.

Try replacing `'+'` with `'reports'` instead:

```
# ...

class Report(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(
        Task,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='reports'  # <<<
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices=Status.CHOICES,
        default=Status.INCOMPLETE
    )
```

Then to get all the `Task`s with their related status, you can use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

```
>>> Task.objects.values('name', 'report__status')
<QuerySet [{'name': 'test', 'report__status': 'OK'}, ...]>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sign `+` is exactly what you don't want to have as `related_name` in this case. It tells Django to not create a backwards relation. Check out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). Chose another valid name or skip this argument, in which case Django will create a reverse relation by default using for the name of the backwards relation the model name lowercased and the suffix `_set` (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for details).

However, in your example if you want to get all reports which are related to a task and the corresponding status you do not necessarily need backwards relationships. Try this:

```
reports = Report.objects.exclude(task__isnull=True).values('task__name', 'status')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `related_name` to something else, like `'reports'` for example:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(
        Task, blank=True, null=True, related_name='reports')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=Status.CHOICES, default=Status.INCOMPLETE)
```

Now if you have a Task object (not queryset), you can get a queryset of it's reports using:

`reports = task.reports.all()`

You can use filter() on the `reports` if you need to.

`reports = task.reports.filter(status='something')`